# Implement a dictionary value into a count down timer

Tags: swift, countdowntimer

I’m making an appllication quiz in which i want to implement the  value of the dictionary to be the intial value of the countdown timer so if the "soft" key is targeted the count down timer starts from 300 instead of 60

````
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let eggTimes :[String:Int]=["Soft":300,"Medium":420,"Hard":720
    ]
  var count: Int = 60
    
    func startCountDown() {
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateCounter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    @objc func updateCounter() {
        if count>0 {
            count-=1
            countDownLabel.text = "\(count)"
            print(count)
        }
    }
    
    @IBOutlet weak var countDownLabel: UILabel!
    @IBAction func hardnessSelected(_ sender: UIButton) {
        startCountDown()
        let hardness=sender.currentTitle!
        let result = eggTimes[hardness]!
        print(result)
        
      
       
       
   
    }
   
    
     
    
} ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    let hardness=sender.currentTitle!
    count = eggTimes[hardness]!
    startCountDown()
```

Comment: I will add that using strings from the UI in an internal dictionary and force unwrapping is not a good practice in general. What if the user is in France or China? The text presented to the user will no longer match the text in your dictionary.

Comment: Maybe  you should consider an enum and use the button.tag to get a value instead

Comment: thanks , i am really have recently started learning coding in general so the concepts you are talking about i have not learn it yet unfortunately

Comment: It's all good. Start with the concepts you understand and build on them a little at a time. Keep trying new things, and you'll get the hang of it in no time. UIButton has a property called tag it can be accessed in the storyboard and set to an Int. And enum just stands for enumeration, you can check it out here: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html. In swift enumerations are very powerful and worth a glance. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Set `count` before starting the countdown

```
@IBAction func hardnessSelected(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let hardness = sender.currentTitle!
    count = eggTimes[hardness]!
    startCountDown()
}
```

---

But it's easier to assign tags to the 3 buttons, the three values 300, 420 and 720.

Then you can delete the dictionary and write

```
@IBAction func hardnessSelected(_ sender: UIButton) {
    count = sender.tag
    startCountDown()
}
```